# Python get property value in dict for large dict

Tags: python

I have a very large dictionary, like this:

```
d['property1']['property2'][0]['property3']['property4']['property5']['property6']
```

I need to get `property6`. What's the simplest way for me to get this value?

I was thinking something like this would work:

```
d.lavel6[0]['property6']
```

Comment: what is the `level6` in your example code?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no generic way to get value of key from nested dict based on levels (due to obvious reasons). But, you may write a function for your specific scenario in order to simplify it. For example:

```
def get_value_from_dict(my_dict, level, key):
    return my_dict['property1']['property2'][level]['property3']['property4']['property5'][key]
```